# Is it possible to change input switch hot keys to another in macOS?

Tags: macos

The default input method switch keys are: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is it possible to bind to other key pairs? Such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Input Sources** you can select the *keyboard shortcut* assigned to, e.g., **Select the previous input source** and then click on, e.g., **^Space** to then change it by then typing the *keyboard shortcut* you want to change it to.

<sup>Note to actually click on the *keyboard shortcut* itself to open up its *edit field*.</sup>

### **Before:**

[image]

### **After:**

[image]

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you very much!